# __meteor_runtime_config__ is not defined [ In Local its working fine ]

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

Hi im getting the below error from today morning. I tried but am unable to fix it.Can anybody have a suggestion on how to overcome this error.I am using meteor with react js.
[image: Please check this attachment]

I am using mup and Below are the logs which im getting when im updating mup reconfig
[image]
[image]

Below is the mup.js file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eGYS.png)
[image]

Comment: Hey @vijay-reddy, I totally missed the case I guess. YOU have develop the app.oleumx.com? I did not see the link in your browser tab when wrote my answer. So you have to better specify your question like: "After deploying my local meteor app to AWS EC2 as https://app.oleumx.com I get this error."

Comment: So any resolution here Tom Freudenberg

Comment: Please add: which Meteor release, do you have a CSP active? How do you deploy the app? MUP or Galaxy? Please add anonymized configs. The runtime config is often missing due to CSP violations or when there was a build error.

Comment: The url just returns a 403, one can't even load the page you are showing. Something is wrong with your deployment. Unless you start answering the questions Tom and Jan have been asking we won't be able to help you Vijay.

Comment: Hey vijay - as Christian and others suggested - please add more information about your deployment and hosting infrastructure. That will help to guide you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have updated the above question

Comment: This issue is related to aws server blocking the meteor.config,js file. Go to AWS WAF page → find the ACL that would control this application → Inspect the requests and find if indeed one of the rulesets is blocking that request. Then you can go to Rules, find that ruleset (in this case " AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet"), click edit, and change LFI_URIPATH to “count”.